# Multi-Language Email template in Service Layer with queue managment

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-email

What is the best option to store HTML and Text email templates for a Multi-language MVC Website?

- Resources (One resource for each language EN/PT/FR - it still distinguish the language from a service layer?)
- Database  (One Column for each language)
- HtML File - One file for each language (file-PT.html, file-EN.html)
- Template.tt

The goal is to send emails as fast as possible to reduce the delay of the user's wait.

I also think that sending in the Service layer is much better then the Web Layer.

As the Links as to be Absolute, I don't think that the need of Views is very useful, but is a solution as Postal an option? Or just simply grab the HTML string from DB or File, replace the String tags with the custom values and send to IIS SMTP to handle the Queue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In my project I store templates in service layer in .cshtml files to have syntax highlight. I use file per culture i.e. TemplateName.[en].cshtml. And I use [Razor engine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) to render templates. Works perfect.

Comment: Hi, thanks. And do you think that, regarding performance, and if the template don't change many times, it's the best option?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if it's the best option about performance - it depends on how to implement other approaches. If you use strongly typed models it would be very fast. The first execution Razor compiles the template and it takes a while (I measured one of my templates - it was about 930ms), but all other execution performs very fast (about 16ms for that template). Remember to cache compiled template (specify cache name).

Answer (score 0):

I would offer you storing email templates in database with a following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE emailTemplates (
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    body VARCHAR(max),
    title VARCHAR(max),
    lcid INT,
    /*and maybe tmplType INT if you have different template types*/
)
```

That'l allow you to simply select template passing `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.LCID` (or even any desired culure id) [and tmplType] as a parameter[s] to find required template. Also you'l be able to Edit and create new templates using admin interface (if have any) or inserting it to database without changing any code and redeploying it to server. And of course you can map template table to some `List<your_template_class>` and store it in cashe, so you won't nee to pull it out of db each time.

Comment: Hi, thanks. And how you manage the queue to send or resend the emails?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cloud or any distributed enviroment to host your application. Then best idea is to use service layer to send the data. So you can use queue to delegate work to sending nodes. It will boost your performance. About templates' source you need to think how will you react to templates' format changes. I think it would be better to use database and cache them on service side.

Comment: Hi, thanks. And how you manage the queue to send or resend the emails?

Comment: Usually queue just hide message when you dequeue it. So you need to remove it later. So in case if you fail to send the message it won't be removed and after a while it will be possible to send it again. I suggest you read book about scaling and patterns http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920023777.do or any other source. There is much more about it.

Comment: I was more talking about maybe store in database and have a process to process the records, send or resend them